# How to read batch messages in confluent kafka python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to read messages from Kafka, so I have written simple consumer to read messages from Kafka.

```
While True:
        message = consumer.poll(timeout=1.0)
        # i am doing something with messages
```

in above code output of message type is message object. how can I get as an array of messages?

is there any possibility ??

Note: Not much consumer configuration basic only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

librdkafka (the underlying C library) only return messages one by one to the application, but internally, messages are fetched by batch from brokers, so there is no performance downside. Messages are queued in an internal buffer, waiting your app to poll.

There are configurations to tune the behaviour:

`fetch.wait.max.ms` (default 100), the time given to broker to accumulate data to send
`fetch.message.max.bytes` (default 1048576, 1GB), the maximum size of batches
`queued.max.messages.kbytes` (default 1000000), the maximum size of data in internal queue. If you don't poll regularly, data won't be purged from queue and you won't be able to fetch any more data.

And many others you can found here: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/0.11.0.x/CONFIGURATION.md

---

If you really want an array of data because of your way to process data, what you can do is call poll with low timeout in a loop like you do, and stop your loop when you have x messages or after y ms, accumulating them in a collection. Process the generated array and repeat the loop.

The same goes for producing: you produce data one by one, but messages are batched before being sent to brokers.

Comment: Can we modify the underlaying C code to return batch of messages ? Because iterating in Python and just getting the message might slowdown the entire process where in case of returning  bunch of messages from C itself will be faster.

Comment: It was the case before, but it was benchmarked there was no downside (in C) to return a message at a time vs returning a batch, due to the way allocation is done. You can use poll(0) in a loop to create your batch - I don't know python well, but perhaps there is an issue (or you could discuss of this) on GitHub, which will be more fitted than stack overflow for this

Comment: For reference (I assume it's yours): https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/252

Comment: Yes, I felt it is better to discuss on GitHub, so I opened the issue there. In a just plain dummy benchmark I found that for loop in Python is a bit slow. So it will be better to do in C api. Thanks :)

Comment: "there is no performance downside" - doesn't that greatly depend on what I'm doing with the records?

Comment: this is such a bad design from application developer perspective. It would be lot more helpful to return a list of messages for every poll or every few polls.

Comment: This is the best explanation for `fetch.wait.max.ms`, `fetch.message.max.bytes` and `queued.max.messages.kbytes` I've seen thus far

Comment: I'm confused by "fetch.message.max.bytes (default 1048576, 1GB)". 1GB in 100ms is the default? Feels like a typo.  The docs say the default is 1048576 which is 1 MiB from my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can just use consumer.consume(batch_size, timeout=1)

```
   batch_size = 10
   while True:
   
    # Poll for new messages
    messages = consumer.consume(batch_size, timeout=1)

    if messages is None:
        continue

    if not messages:
        # No messages received
        continue

    for message in messages:
        if message.error():
            print(f"Error consuming message: {message.error()}")
        else:
            print(f"Received message: {message.value()}")
```